# Passing contents of Vector to a function

Tags: c++, vector

I'm attempting to use the contents of a vector within a function, which has it's own .cpp and header file.

The header file has the declaration
    `void drawIsland(int);`

And the .cpp file has the definition
        `void drawIsland(vector<int>&Island)`
        `{//code here...};`

However attempting to call the function within the main .cpp file gives me the error that "no suitable conversion function from "std::vector>" to "int" exists", and the code will not run.

The vector i'm trying to pass has already been initialised with a user defined number of ints each all at 0.

Any suggestions to how to get the vector into the function?

Comment: Why do you declare the function to take an `int` in the header file when you use a `vector` in the cpp file?

Comment: If you do not understand why you can't define a `drawIsLand(vector<int> &)`, declare a `drawIsland(int)`, and expect everything to work, then you need to spend more time reading your C++ book.

Comment: this is something that every c++ book has, no need to ask community, you are going to waste your and others time (not to mention you will be downvoted a lot for questions like this)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the declaration (`.h`) match the definition (`.cpp`)!

The call site has only seen `void drawIsland(int)`, so how can it think it is ok to pass a `vector`?

So your header should look like:

```
#ifndef INCLUDED_DRAW_ISLAND
#define INCLUDED_DRAW_ISLAND

#include <vector>

void drawIsland(std::vector<int> &island);

#endif
```

Your cpp should look like:

```
#include <draw_island.h>

void drawIsland(std::vector<int> &island)
{
    // do stuff...
}
```

And your main should look like:

```
#include <draw_island.h>
#include <vector> // not strictly necessary

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> island{1,2,3,4,5};
    drawIsland(island);
}
```

Comment: After making the declaration match the definition, i now get errors saying 'vector': undeclared identifier, and type 'int' unexpected within the header file.

Comment: @aftershock995 Not sure what you are missing, since you didn't provide a [mcve], but I added examples of how the files should look.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of examples on my end, but what you suggested managed to help out, and i got the vector into my function. Thanks alot!